# Clicking browser back button to search page shows error in Chrome

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

The `SearchController` code is this:

```
namespace Bejebeje.Mvc.Controllers
{
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using Bejebeje.Models.Search;
  using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
  using Services.Services.Interfaces;

  public class SearchController : Controller
  {
    private readonly ILyricsService _lyricsService;

    private readonly IArtistsService _artistsService;

    public SearchController(
      ILyricsService lyricsService,
      IArtistsService artistsService)
    {
      _lyricsService = lyricsService;
      _artistsService = artistsService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
      SearchViewModel viewModel = new SearchViewModel();

      return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchTerm)
    {
      SearchViewModel viewModel = new SearchViewModel();

      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
      {
        return View(viewModel);
      }

      viewModel.SearchTerm = searchTerm;

      viewModel.Artists = await _artistsService
        .SearchArtistsAsync(searchTerm);

      viewModel.Lyrics = await _lyricsService
        .SearchLyricsAsync(searchTerm);

      return View(viewModel);
    }
  }
}
```

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. [Go to site](https://bejebeje.com/)
2. Search for an artist (e.g. Şivan)
3. Click artist (Şivan Perwer)
4. Now click the browser's back button
5. Chrome shows the following error:

   [image: chrome error on back button]

How does this happen and how can I get it to behave like the search on Stack Overflow? On Stack Overflow, if I go to a search result, then click the browser's back button, it just shows the previous results, which is the behaviour I'm after.

The code for the application is open source and [available on GitHub](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/bejebeje/tree/main).

Comment: This is chrome default behavior and just for posting method. The stackoverflow's search is get method not post method, so the chrome is not show the same error. So you could just get instead of the post to avoid chrome behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try changing it to a GET request <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is chrome default behavior and just for posting method.  Normally, for this kind of issue, we could have below approach.

1.You could consider modifying the httppost method to get method like SO do.

More details, you could refer to below example:

View:

```
<form  method="get">
    <input name="searchTerm" type="text"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>

</form>
```

Controller:

```
    public IActionResult Index(string? searchTerm)
    { 
        return View();
    }
```

Result:

[image]

2. For normal posting, like storing some data into the database, you could add redirect after posting completely.

3.For normal posting, like storing some data into the database, you could also consider using the ajax method.